# Rails most efficient way to pull out data from simple model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got two simple models - `Campaign` and `CampaignCode` from which I will have to pull out number of already used `CampaignCode`. Because it's a large amount of data (200k codes for just one campaign) I'm wondering which way will be most efficient to do so?

`query`

```
CampaignCode.where(state: 'used').count
```

I think this `query` solving the problem only with small piece of data, should I use `include` or maybe some join table?

`campaign` model

```
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  end_date           :date
#  id                 :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  name               :text             not null
#  start_date         :date
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null

class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :campaign_codes

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

`campaign_code` model

```
#created_at         :datetime         not null
#campaign_id        :bigint(8)
#state              :integer
#uid                :string           not null, primary key
#updated_at         :datetime         not null

class CampaignCode < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :uid

  belongs_to :campaign

  validates :uid, uniqueness: true
end
```

Comment: What you have should be fine.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `users.state` column in the database?.

Comment: @JoshBrody Even if it will be a query for million campaign codes in every page refresh? I have to provide this data in one endpoint which will return number of used campaign codes for every refreshment

Comment: @spickermann nope I don't have it

Comment: Do you need the count of all codes or all codes per campaign?

Comment: @spickermann all codes per campaign but in the view there will be hundred campaigns with hundred of thousand codes

Comment: to make your view lightweight why don't you use pagination. So you don't have to make unnecessary query for all campaign code until your client want to see that.

Comment: I'm wondering how you plan to show 200k codes in page without bothering the user. What's the case, is the most important here.

Comment: Have you considered using counter cache

Comment: How about using database triggers? Whenever a code is used you can just increase the count. There's one handy gem for this as well: https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you need speed you gotta use direct SQL and use the tricks of your database.

I would make a custom query in your model (if PostgreSQL):

```
def self.count_used_codes
  sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT count(*) FROM campaign_codes WHERE state == 'used';
  SQL
  self.find_by_sql(sql)
end
```

Then use with

```
CampaignCode.count_used_codes
```

Then you also give yourself some flexibility to optimize based on your specific usage. You can also try out estimated counts which can be much faster if you aren't worried about accuracy, but that stuff is a bit beyond what I'm knowledgeable in.

I've also seen people make a specific sql folder in app and then reference complex queries in there to keep it all clean.